# RAID Array gone to read-only

Tags: filesystems, raid, software-raid, readonly

I've created a virtual machine running on KVM only for testing and learning purposes. During the installation RAID 1 array has been configured with 3 disks for root and 3 for boot. After some playing and testing I've decide to write zeroes to one of the drives and check what will happens:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/vdc2
```

After while the system gone to read-only, but there weren't any errors in mdamd.

*dmesg:*

```
[ 2177.091939] RAID1 conf printout:
[ 2177.091947]  --- wd:2 rd:3
[ 2177.091954]  disk 0, wo:0, o:1, dev:vda2
[ 2177.091956]  disk 1, wo:0, o:1, dev:vdb2
[ 2177.091958]  disk 2, wo:1, o:1, dev:vdc2
[ 2177.095315] md: recovery of RAID array md1
[ 2177.095321] md: minimum _guaranteed_  speed: 1000 KB/sec/disk.
[ 2177.095323] md: using maximum available idle IO bandwidth (but not more than 200000 KB/sec) for recovery.
[ 2177.095330] md: using 128k window, over a total of 9792512k.
[ 2217.132610] RAID1 conf printout:
[ 2217.132616]  --- wd:2 rd:3
[ 2217.132622]  disk 0, wo:0, o:1, dev:vda1
[ 2217.132625]  disk 1, wo:0, o:1, dev:vdb1
[ 2217.132626]  disk 2, wo:1, o:1, dev:vdc1
[ 2217.135129] md: delaying recovery of md0 until md1 has finished (they share one or more physical units)
[ 2225.567664] md: md1: recovery done.
[ 2225.572072] md: recovery of RAID array md0
[ 2225.572081] md: minimum _guaranteed_  speed: 1000 KB/sec/disk.
[ 2225.572083] md: using maximum available idle IO bandwidth (but not more than 200000 KB/sec) for recovery.
[ 2225.572087] md: using 128k window, over a total of 682432k.
[ 2225.574833] RAID1 conf printout:
[ 2225.574836]  --- wd:3 rd:3
[ 2225.574904]  disk 0, wo:0, o:1, dev:vda2
[ 2225.574906]  disk 1, wo:0, o:1, dev:vdb2
[ 2225.574908]  disk 2, wo:0, o:1, dev:vdc2
[ 2229.036805] md: md0: recovery done.
[ 2229.042732] RAID1 conf printout:
[ 2229.042736]  --- wd:3 rd:3
[ 2229.042740]  disk 0, wo:0, o:1, dev:vda1
[ 2229.042742]  disk 1, wo:0, o:1, dev:vdb1
[ 2229.042744]  disk 2, wo:0, o:1, dev:vdc1
[ 5241.129626] md/raid1:md1: Disk failure on vdc2, disabling device.
               md/raid1:md1: Operation continuing on 2 devices.
[ 5241.131639] RAID1 conf printout:
[ 5241.131642]  --- wd:2 rd:3
[ 5241.131645]  disk 0, wo:0, o:1, dev:vda2
[ 5241.131647]  disk 1, wo:0, o:1, dev:vdb2
[ 5241.131648]  disk 2, wo:1, o:0, dev:vdc2
[ 5241.131655] RAID1 conf printout:
[ 5241.131656]  --- wd:2 rd:3
[ 5241.131658]  disk 0, wo:0, o:1, dev:vda2
[ 5241.131684]  disk 1, wo:0, o:1, dev:vdb2
[ 5326.850032] md: unbind<vdc2>
[ 5326.850050] md: export_rdev(vdc2)
[ 5395.301755] md: export_rdev(vdc2)
[ 5395.312985] md: bind<vdc2>
[ 5395.315022] RAID1 conf printout:
[ 5395.315024]  --- wd:2 rd:3
[ 5395.315027]  disk 0, wo:0, o:1, dev:vda2
[ 5395.315029]  disk 1, wo:0, o:1, dev:vdb2
[ 5395.315031]  disk 2, wo:1, o:1, dev:vdc2
[ 5395.318161] md: recovery of RAID array md1
[ 5395.318168] md: minimum _guaranteed_  speed: 1000 KB/sec/disk.
[ 5395.318170] md: using maximum available idle IO bandwidth (but not more than 200000 KB/sec) for recovery.
[ 5395.318174] md: using 128k window, over a total of 9792512k.
[ 5443.707445] md: md1: recovery done.
[ 5443.712678] RAID1 conf printout:
[ 5443.712682]  --- wd:3 rd:3
[ 5443.712686]  disk 0, wo:0, o:1, dev:vda2
[ 5443.712688]  disk 1, wo:0, o:1, dev:vdb2
[ 5443.712689]  disk 2, wo:0, o:1, dev:vdc2
[ 8017.777012] EXT4-fs error (device md1): ext4_lookup:1584: inode #36: comm systemd-sysv-ge: deleted inode referenced: 135
[ 8017.782244] Aborting journal on device md1-8.
[ 8017.785487] EXT4-fs (md1): Remounting filesystem read-only
[ 8017.876415] EXT4-fs error (device md1): ext4_lookup:1584: inode #36: comm systemd: deleted inode referenced: 137
```

*cat /proc/mdstat:*

```
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md1 : active raid1 vdb2[1] vda2[0]
      9792512 blocks super 1.2 [3/2] [UU_]

md0 : active raid1 vdc1[2] vdb1[1] vda1[0]
      682432 blocks super 1.2 [3/3] [UUU]

unused devices: <none>
```

I've tried to mount back the root as read-write without success:

*mount -o remount /*

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

then:

*fsck -Af*

```
fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I was hopping that without to remove the vdc2 drive I will successfully re-balancing it, but I was wrong. The broken drive has been removed:

```
mdadm --manage /dev/md1 --fail /dev/vdc2
mdadm --manage /dev/md1 --remove /dev/vdc2
```

And try to delete and create the drive again using fdisk or cfdisk but I've got the same error: *Segmentation fault (core dumped)*

I am pasting the status of md1 and the drive using mdadm:

*mdadm -D /dev/md1*

```
/dev/md1:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Mon Nov  7 21:22:29 2016
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 9792512 (9.34 GiB 10.03 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 9792512 (9.34 GiB 10.03 GB)
   Raid Devices : 3
  Total Devices : 2
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Tue Nov  8 02:38:26 2016
          State : clean, degraded 
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           Name : ubuntu-raid:1  (local to host ubuntu-raid)
           UUID : c846618f:d77238fe:95edac3d:dd19e295
         Events : 108

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0     253        2        0      active sync   /dev/vda2
       1     253       18        1      active sync   /dev/vdb2
       4       0        0        4      removed
```

*mdadm -E /dev/vdc2*

```
/dev/vdc2:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : c846618f:d77238fe:95edac3d:dd19e295
           Name : ubuntu-raid:1  (local to host ubuntu-raid)
  Creation Time : Mon Nov  7 21:22:29 2016
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 19585024 (9.34 GiB 10.03 GB)
     Array Size : 9792512 (9.34 GiB 10.03 GB)
    Data Offset : 16384 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=16296 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 25a823f7:a301598a:91f9c66b:cc27d311

    Update Time : Tue Nov  8 02:20:34 2016
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : d6d7fc77 - correct
         Events : 101


   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.1
Kernel: 4.4.0-31-generic
mdadm version: v3.3

So I have a two questions: why this happen, what is the main reason to be not able to mount the array read-write and the second question is how to prevent this in future. Of course this is a testing environment but I am looking for a way to fix it without rebooting or something similar

Comment: filling one active device of a raid array with zeroes is not a real life failure simulation.

Comment: I've just search a way to broke the system and this attempt was successful on 100%. The system can go to read-only with a lot of scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Linux `md` system depends on the component drives of your RAID array to either provide good data, or provide no data.  In a real-world failure situation, this is a reasonable assumption: disks have error-correction information on them, and it is extremely unlikely that a bad sector will corrupt itself in a way that can't be detected.

By writing zeroes to a disk, you bypass this protection.  The `md` system thinks the data is still good, and it passes the corrupt data on up to the filesystem layer, which reacts badly.  Since you're using RAID 1, `md` will balance reads across all drives to increase performance; the crashes you're getting are because pieces of `mount` and `fsck` are getting read from the bad drive.

To recover, remove the failed disk from the system entirely (since you're using a VM, do this using the VM's management tools; if this was a physical system, you'd unplug the drive).  This will force the `md` system to realize the drive has failed and stop reading from it; you can then perform any filesystem-level recovery needed.

If you want to play this sort of game with your disks, format them with ZFS or BTRFS: these filesystems don't make the assumption of "good data or no data", and use checksums to spot bad data being read from the disk.